# how to display the results of npm audit in jenkins and fail the build

Tags: jenkins, npm, npm-audit

I would like to run the npm command [npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit) as part of the ci build and somehow display the output in a jenkins ci build.

If a critical vulnerability is found, I would like to fail the current build by returning a non zero exit code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Was this for a personal project or with a team?
If it was with a team, did you end up implementing this? I'm confused why you would want the build to fail. Wouldn't it require all PR authors to make the same fix in each PR branch before successfully building?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any plugins that would achive this but some manual parsing might work(if you are using a pipeline).

```
def output = sh script: "npm audit", returnStdout: true
def summary = output.split("\n")[-1] //get the summary from the last line
...
```

You then could use some regex or other string manipulation to find the number after critical. You also could use archiveArtifacts to save the entire output in the build history.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired on [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1011520/Jenkins-Pipeline-Step-Node-Security-Project), I've realized this by creating a custom 'Compiler Warnings parser';

1. install [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin)
2. configure custom parser:
   Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> 'Compiler Warnings' section
   **Name**: NPM audit analyzer
   **Link name**: NPM audit analyzer
   **Trend report name**: Detected Vulnerabilities
   **Regular Expression**: `[\w+-]+\s+([\w+-]+)\s+([\w\.-@]+)\s+(>=\s)*([\w\.-@]+)\s+(.+?(?=http))([\w\.-@]+)\s+(.*)`
   **Mapping script**:

```groofy
import hudson.plugins.warnings.parser.Warning  
import hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.Priority

priority = Priority.HIGH;
if ( "low" == matcher.group(2)  ) {
    priority = Priority.LOW;
}
else if ( "moderate" == matcher.group(2) ) {
    priority = Priority.NORMAL;
}

String msg = "Vulnerability found in '" + matcher.group(1) + "' (" + matcher.group(6) + ") , prio: " + matcher.group(2) + " Fix: " + matcher.group(5) + " info: " + matcher.group(5);  
return new Warning('package.json', 0, 'NSP Warning', matcher.group(1), msg, priority);
```

3. configure job;
4. Add **Execute shell** build step:

```bash
npm install  
# parseable report for 'compile warning post build step'  
npm audit --parseable >> npm_audit_report_parseable.txt || true # suppress npm audit error code
```

5. Add **[Deprecated] Scan for compiler warnings** post build step:
   'Scan workspace files' -> **File patters**: npm_audit_report_parseable.txt
   'Scan workspace files' -> **Parser**: NPM audit analyzer

Optionally you can configure 'Health/Status thresholds'; this determines when a build *fails*, and when it is marked as *unstable*.

---

Another solutions: use the [Dependency-Check Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dependency-check-plugin)

1. install [Dependency-Check Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dependency-check-plugin)
2. configure a 'Dependency-Check' global tool:
   Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> 'Dependency-Check'  -> 'Add Dependency-Check'
3. configure job;
4. Add **Invoke Dependency-Check** build step:
   **Dependency-Check installation**: choose the configured global tool
   I also configured additional **Arguments** `--scan /non/existing/dir` to avoid finding exploits in installed package related files like 'demo', 'docs', etc. because the 'dependency check plugin' performs a full recursive file scan which we do not need because the npm scanner finds the 'npm audit' findings already.
5. Add **Publish Dependency-Check results** post build step:
   **XML Report**: **/dependency-check-report.xml